# Reagarding stdController.getRecord();

Tags: apex

I am not getting any value when I use `Quote q = (Quote)stdController.getRecord();`

`q` is empty. Can any one suggest what would be the reason for this?

Comment: It would help everybody if you posted more context (your Visualforce page, the full controller class, etc).

Answer (score 7):

If you want any fields value then you need add the field api name in standard controller

```
public ctrl(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
     stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'Name', 'PriceBook2Id', 'CurrencyIsoCode'});
}
```

So basically when we use `getRecord()`

> getRecord()
>
> Returns the record that is currently in context, based on the value of
>   the id query string parameter in the Visualforce page URL.

Use `addFields(fieldNames)` method

> When a Visualforce page is loaded, the fields accessible to the page
>   are based on the fields referenced in the Visualforce markup. This
>   method adds a reference to each field specified in fieldNames so that
>   the controller can explicitly access those fields as well.

---

If **q** is empty means you are not adding id in url

example 
**/apex/VFPAGE?id=quoteId here**

---

If we debug

```
Quote q = (Quote)stdController.getRecord();
system.debug('======'+q);
```

If output is like below means id is not passed in above page url

> |======Quote :{}

If you output like below then id in url

> DEBUG|======Quote :{Id=0Q09000000K8YjGAAV}

Comment: My question is different. Quote q=(Quote)stdController.getRecord(); It should  show record for Quote

Comment: @Gayathri The only reason if id is not present in url

Comment: ok....how can I get id in the URL?I mean where I need to modify and what needs to be added?

Comment: `ap1.salesforce.com/apex/VFPAGE?id=quoteId here` like this add your pagename and your quote id then only it will return the quote is in controller

Comment: In Vfpage I need to add some where or everytime I need to add like this

Comment: if you are using standardcontroller. Then everytime you need to add id

Comment: I just modified in the URl , ran the vfpage and checked my debuglogs, its still empty

Comment: I have written Extension for Quote object in that I am not getting id

Comment: @Gayathri Can you just add here your url?

Comment: https://cs2.salesforce.com/066R00000000sNcIAI?id=quoteId as I already have vfpage I am just appending id to it

Comment: no  @Gayathri **cs2.salesforce.com/apex/you vf page Name ?id=quoteId** quoteId means not just string your need to record Id ex. https://ratan.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/NEWOPP?id=0069000000K8YjG

Comment: N.B. `addFields(..)` can't be used in the context of a testmethod if an existing Quote is provided to the extension class. Needs to be prefixed by `if (!Test.isRunningTest())`

Comment: @crop1645 Yes Agree, We have to use `if (!Test.isRunningTest())`